# Iterate over array with $.each

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following JSON structure and I'm trying to grab the 'title' value

```
{
    "ok": true,
    "messages": [{
        "type": "message",
        "subtype": "file_share",
        "file": {
            "name": "Football_and_Hurling_Images.txt",
            "title": "Football and Hurling Images"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: `object.messages[0].file.title`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/yz27gazc/

Comment: Gladly but I think you need to submit it as an answer rather than a comment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Iterate like this, in case of multiple `messages`:

```js
  var obj = {
    "ok": true,
    "messages": [{
      "type": "message",
      "subtype": "file_share",
      "file": {
        "name": "Football_and_Hurling_Images.txt",
        "title": "Football and Hurling Images"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "message2",
      "subtype": "file_share",
      "file": {
        "name": "Football_and_Hurling_Images.txt",
        "title": "Football and Hurling Images2"
      }
    }, {
      "type": "message3",
      "subtype": "file_share",
      "file": {
        "name": "Football_and_Hurling_Images.txt",
        "title": "Football and Hurling Images3"
      }
    }]
  }
  $.each(obj.messages, function(index, msg) {
    //console.log(msg);
    console.log(msg.file.title);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great! Thanks for the expanded answer

Answer (score 0):

this code will work for you.

```
 YourJSON.messages[0].file.title;
```